# jquery chain animation mousenter mouseleave

Tags: jquery, animation, mouseevent, chaining

Hello I have the following issue I have 12 images that on hover a chain of animation is being played out on each one of them depending on which the mouse entered. I want each animation to be executed one after another, but when I hover fast over the images or even if the animation is not complete then the animation doesn't work as intended.I've been trying to figure it out all morning but no luck. On the mouseleave event I didnt make chain animation just for debugging purposes, but I need it to be chained. Check a live demo of the problem here: http://www.evented.gr/evd2/main.php (the 4x3 = 12 images).

Here is the code:

```
$('#upcoming-events .upcoming-event').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this.parentNode).find('div.ue-category').stop(true,true).animate({height:'0px',queue:false},100,function(){
        $(this.parentNode.parentNode).animate({backgroundColor:'#a00000',queue:false},250,function(){
            $(this.parentNode).find('div.slider').animate({height:'221px',queue:false},250,function(){
                $(this.parentNode).find('div.ue-corner').animate({width:'58px',queue:false},100,function(){

                });     
            });
        });
    });

});

$('#upcoming-events .upcoming-event').mouseleave(function(){

    $(this.parentNode).find('div.slider').animate({height:'50px',queue:false},250);
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor:'#fff',queue:false},250);
    $(this.parentNode).find('div.ue-category').animate({height:'20px',queue:false},100);    
    $(this).find('div.ue-corner').animate({width:'0px',queue:false},100);

});
```

Comment: `return this;  });` this is how it should end...

Comment: Could you be a little more specifc please ?

Comment: well to remain chain-ability with jquery you must use `return this;` or `return $(this);` at the end of the `function` on the `.mouseleave(function(){ .... return this;});` hope it helps...

Comment: Chaining is not the issue here. MouseLeave is like that because i was testing something the issue is that if you hover over an item too fast and move on to the next the animation chain is being broken.

Comment: use `.stop` in that case just before animate,also you may want to use the `.stop(true,true)` or a combination of true,false values there :)

Comment: nevermind i got it working withe the use of .delay() prior to every animate with no nested animation chains so each animation triggers at the same time but executes at different time